In JavaFX, how to wrap text without breaking the words?
I use setMaxWidth to make TextFlow automatically wrap text. But if its width is small, it will break words like the following.
We only 
travele 
d 
togethe 
r for 
10 
years.

Is there a way to wrap the text without breaking the words?
I don't find any way to do this.

It is not a supported platform feature.  If you want this feature, you will need to implement it yourself (perhaps difficult unless proportional fonts are used) or try to find a third party that assists with that (of which I know none).

I've found a workaround by avoiding its width smaller than the longest word's length: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/wrap-text-without-breaking-the-words.160966/
